# What is the difference between Brisk LR14ZC and LR14ZC-1 spark plugs?

Tags: sparkplugs

What is the difference (besides price) between Brisk LR14ZC and Brisk LR14ZC-1 spark plugs?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Brisk website](http://www.briskracing.com/identification-and-construction), the difference in the two is the gap of the spark plug. The "-1" extension, says it should be gapped between 1.0 and 1.1 mm. Without the extension, the gap should be .4 to .9 mm.